# implications of setting enableReinitialize in redux-form

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form

I have an app that  is a multistep wizard where I have a higher order component that creates each form in the process, currently I have each form component set with the following options:

```
{
  form: formName,
  validate: validate,
  destroyOnUnmount: false,
  keepDirtyOnReinitialize: true,
  forceUnregisterOnUnmount: true
}
```

I currently am not setting `enableReinitialize` so it is defaulting to false.

I update the redux state every time the user goes to the next step.

This is a problem in the wizard scenario because if the user clicks back and then forward again they are losing some state because fields are getting set back to the `initialValues` in that particular step.

What are the repercussions with regards to performance with setting `enableReinitialize` to true, does it reset every time the state changes or just every time the component loads?

Answer (score 0):

The redux-form [docs](https://redux-form.com/7.0.4/examples/wizard/) have a really useful guide for wizard forms. What you are looking for isn't `enableReinitialize`, but to `destroyOnUnmount` to `false`.

The docs are pretty straight forward I think.

Comment: yes but then the fields lose their values if you click back without updating the global state

Comment: i want to keep state in redux-firm state until it is valid and then update

Comment: Why would that happen? `redux-form` is the one managing the state of the form, and unless destroyed (which is prevented with `destroyOnUnmount` set to `false`, not `true` just edited that on my answer) they shouldn't be lost.

Comment: I have `destroyOnUnmount=false`.  Maybe I should not be using `initialValues` at all.

Comment: You shouldn't :) `initialValues` is for just that, initializing the form and setting the 'pristine' values. The wizard form should work just like the docs example. If you could add some code to your question too see what's happening if you still can't fix it could help.

Comment: i think that was my misunderstanding, i thought i would need initialvalues each time i re-entered the form.  but it should all be in the redux form-state.

Answer (score 0):

Use this on Wizard from on Redux forms to preserve field values.

```
const formWrapped = reduxForm({
    form: 'yourFormName',
    destroyOnUnmount: false, // <------ preserve form data
    forceUnregisterOnUnmount: true
})(YourComponentName);
```